# Timer.equals() not working in TomEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb-3.1, apache-tomee

I am developing a webapp (.war file), but now I need to implement timerservice, so I am using ejb's timer service. I am storing a object with on of the variables being timerhandle of the timer created, in a local file. There will be many objects appended to same file as you create new timers. When the timeout occurs, I open the local file and finding the write object using equals method:

```
public void programmaticTimeout(Timer timer) {

try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(db);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);){
            while((temp = (Rules)ois.readObject()) != null){
                System.out.println(temp.getName());
                if(timer.equals(temp.getTimerHandle().getTimer())){
                    System.out.println("Time handler found!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
}
```

But this is resulting in always choosing the first object. Can anyone explain how to resolve this?

**EDIT :**
As suggested by @Romain Manni-Bucau, I am using getInfo() method as follows:

```
public TimerHandle setTimer(ScheduleExpression schedule, Rules rule) {
    Timer timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedule, new TimerConfig(rule, true));
    return timer.getHandle();
}

@Timeout
public void programmaticTimeout(Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("Programmatic timeout fired!");
    this.setLastProgrammaticTimeout(new Date());
    Rules temp = (Rules)timer.getInfo();
        if(temp.getType().equals("campaigns"))
            try {
                handleCampaigns(temp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Now, I've implemented web page (and corresponding servlet) for setting new rules by choosing time and frequency of the event. As new rules are created the servlet makes call to:

```
setTimer(schedule,newrule);
```

Now, if I created multiple rules (multiple timers with corresponding events), only the first timer is getting fired but with the event of the last timer. I don't know why is this happening. Am I doing wrong? I've switched from TomCat to TomEE for the timeservice. Should I add any dependencies to pom.xml for this shift?

Screenshot: https://postimg.org/image/9jde59nep/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use getInfo() to match the right timer?

Comment: I finally settled for  this method, but is there a problem with Timer.equals() in TomEE? I've read that Timer.equals() must be implemented by the container, though I didn't try other servers than TomEE.

Comment: I have other problem with TomEE when using getInfo(), I've edited the question. Could you please look into it?

Comment: it is a bit more vicious cause you serialize it, not sure this part is well specified. That said tomee can get a more sensible equals implementation too but using info to hold business code metada is also a good practise.

edit: for info, do you set it when creating the timer?

Comment: Yes, I create it when setting the timer. I've edited the question to include screenshot also.

Comment: Do you think you can write a small (failling) test reproducing the issue? (using http://tomee.apache.org/developer/testing/applicationcomposer/index.html for instance). Cause serialization aside it looks close to https://github.com/rmannibucau/scheedule/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rmannibucau/scheedule/service/schedule/Scheduler.java#L133

Comment: I wrote a test case but the test case works, Its highly similar to original one. Now I am mad. I didn't use ApplicationComposer because it works.